# Random partition of an interval – Dirichlet distributed?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, geometric-probability

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_N \sim \operatorname{Unif}[0,1]$ and consider the intervals between successive order statistics: $[0, X_{(1)}], [X_{(1)}, X_{(2)}], \ldots, [X_{(N)}, 1]$.

What is the distribution of this vector of interval lengths?

I hypothesize that it is Dirichlet$(1, \ldots, 1)$, but I cannot prove it and my literature search is taking me to obscure 1800s papers.  Any thoughts?

Comment: This follows from the fact that the joint density of the order statistics $X_{(j)}$ is constant and the change of variable from the $x_{(j)}$ to the lengths has constant Jacobian (it's linear), so the probability is obtained by integrating a constant, which is exactly how the Dirichlet distribution with all parameters equal to $1$ works.

Comment: Of course, that's assuming that the $X_j$ are independent; you obviously can't say anything in general.

Comment: I believe your guess is right, but it's hard to see this as research-level math even if it hasn't been published. Christian Remling's comment is terse but it looks like the right idea. I think he meant the whole vector of all $N$ order statistics rather than for just one value of $j.$

Comment: Pretty sure it has been published, many times. For example, Springer's Encyclopedia of Mathematics, [Dirichlet distribution](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) explicitly says the distribution is Dirichlet. (FWIW [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#When_each_alpha_is_1) also says it, but without an inline reference.)

Comment: Did you take a look into \item {\bf Bertoin, J.:} The asymptotic behavior of fragmentation processes, J. European Math. Soc., 5 (2003) 395 - 416 and
\item {\bf Bertoin, J.:} Different Aspects of a Model for Random Fragmentation Processes. ccsd-00005175, version 1, 7 Feb 2005, 26 S.